# numpy matrix trickery - sum of inverse times matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I'm trying to do the following, and repeat until convergence:

[image]

where each X<sub>i</sub> is `n x p`, and there are `r` of them in an `r x n x p` array called `samples`. `U` is `n x n`, `V` is `p x p`. (I'm getting the MLE of a [matrix normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution).)
The sizes are all potentially large-ish; I'm expecting things at least on the order of  `r = 200`, `n = 1000`, `p = 1000`.

My current code does

```
V = np.einsum('aji,jk,akl->il', samples, np.linalg.inv(U) / (r*n), samples)
U = np.einsum('aij,jk,alk->il', samples, np.linalg.inv(V) / (r*p), samples)
```

This works okay, but of course you're never supposed to actually find the inverse and multiply stuff by it. It'd also be good if I could somehow exploit the fact that U and V are symmetric and positive-definite.
I'd love to be able to just calculate the Cholesky factor of U and V in the iteration, but I don't know how to do that because of the sum.

I could avoid the inverse by doing something like

```
V = sum(np.dot(x.T, scipy.linalg.solve(A, x)) for x in samples)
```

(or something similar that exploited the psd-ness), but then there's a Python loop, and that makes the numpy fairies cry.

I could also imagine reshaping `samples` in such a way that I could get an array of `A^-1 x` using `solve` for every `x` without having to do a Python loop, but that makes a big auxiliary array that's a waste of memory.

Is there some linear algebra or numpy trick I can do to get the best of all three: no explicit inverses, no Python looping, and no big aux arrays? Or is my best bet implementing the one with a Python loop in a faster language and calling out to it? (Just porting it directly to Cython might help, but would still involve a lot of Python method calls; but maybe it wouldn't be too much trouble to make the relevant blas/lapack routines directly without too much trouble.)

(As it turns out, I don't actually need the matrices `U` and `V` in the end - just their determinants, or actually just the determinant of their Kronecker product. So if anyone has a clever idea for how to do less work and still get the determinants out, that would be much appreciated.)

Comment: Nicely written question. My brain is not functioning well today, but I just wanted to recommend that you post at least the mathematical parts from the beginning and end to math.stackexchange.com in case you are missing an obvious shortcut. You're right, it *feels* like there *might* be a way to exploit the spd matrix properties but I can't see it either.

Comment: @MrE Thanks for the suggestion; [I've posted it there also](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/298512/19147).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until someone comes up with a more inspired answer, if I were you, I'd let the fairies cry...

```
r, n, p = 200, 400, 400

X = np.random.rand(r, n, p)
U = np.random.rand(n, n)

In [2]: %timeit np.sum(np.dot(x.T, np.linalg.solve(U, x)) for x in X)
1 loops, best of 3: 9.43 s per loop

In [3]: %timeit np.dot(X[0].T, np.linalg.solve(U, X[0]))
10 loops, best of 3: 45.2 ms per loop
```

So having a python loop, and having to sum all the results together, is taking 390 ms more than 200 times what it takes to solve each of the 200 systems that have to be solved. You'd get less than a 5% improvement if the looping and the summing were free. There may be some calling a python function overhead also, but it's probably still going to be negligible against the actual time solving the equations, no matter what language you code it in.

Comment: Hmm...good point. I stupidly did my timing of the `einsum` method versus the `solve` method in a case with very large `r` and very small `n` and `p`, where of course it makes sense that the Python loop overhead would be much more important. I'll try it on my real data tomorrow and see what the comparison is.

Comment: It turns out that doing a python loop with `scipy.linalg.cho_solve` is fast enough for my needs. I'm still curious if there's an algorithmic speedup to be had, and so I'm leaving the math.SE question open.